# Re MF Pack Win7 N SP1 KB968211 How much time needed to download/install?

Tags: windows-7, window

I had Win 7 but during maintance Win 7 N was installed. I had no idea of the effect re Media Player 12.

How long should it take to download/install  MFP  Win 7 N SP1 KB968211 ?

I've tried but HOURS past with no sign of progress ?

Thank You, RCG

Comment: This depends on the speed of the system. If its already been hours there is something wrong.  Seems like you should just install Windows 7 if you actually require WMP.

Answer (score 1):

It's completely dependant on the speed of your internet and machine.

The update is either 278MB or 303MB dependant on whether you are using windows 32 or 64 bit.  You can use [This download time calculator](http://www.numion.com/calculators/time.html) to determine a rough download time.

Install time will vary by the amount of your power.. a quad core with 6GB RAM ona 64 bit OS will be very different to a dual core 2GB 32 bit OS install.

If you are having problems, google is your friend.  I've just googled "KB968211 install hangs" and have come across several aticles.  A lot of them say that using msconfig to disable a lot of startup items helps.  2 Articles said to check C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log for a reason why it is hanging.  An article on technet also pointed to Antivirus scanning to be the cause of the application install hanging.

Of all the articles, [This technet article](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/2cc07aae-1bae-4f05-8b83-e608cca54492/kb968211-installation-on-windows-7-n-edition-hangs-on-installation-of-media-feature-pack?forum=w7itpromedia) seemed to help the most.